# ActiveX button to clear cells with a specific RGB color

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm looking for a VBA code in `Excel 2010` to create an ActiveX button which allows the user to clear the content of cells (but not their format) if these cells contain a specific RGB color.

Furthermore, I want the user to confirm (with a message box) he is sure to clear the content of these cells with a password fir instance.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some simple code that goes through 100 cells and if the color is red, it clears their contents:

```
    Sub delete_if_red()
        For c = 1 To 10
            For r = 1 To 10
                If Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = 255 Then Cells(r, c).Value = ""
            Next r
        Next c
    End Sub
```

If you want to look for a different color, I recommend recording a macro where you change the background color of a cell to that color, then look at the code to get the index of the desired color. Then change "255" to that number.

You'll also need to make a button and assign the new macro to the button.